# sqlite versus csv file for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, sqlite, uitableview, csv

We have about 10 sqlite files getting downloaded in our app and each of which contains about 4000 rows. We process that data and display it in a tableview. We are running into speed and memory issues when scrolling through the tableview.

We were thinking whether instead of sqlite files, if we have csv files or some other format, can we get better performance than sqlite? I have read that xml or json won't help since the number of records is too huge and parsing time would go up.

Please suggest.

Comment: Have you/is there any way to profile it?  Can you add performance timers to see exactly where the bottleneck is occuring?

Comment: The memory issue is because we are trying to get as much data as possible from the sqlite into an array. This makes the scrolling faster since we read from the array and display the data. However, the more data we put in the array, the sooner we run into memory issues and we have to release off some data and then may be refetch it if the user scrolls to that position in the tableview where it was displayed. We also tried fetching the data for only the visible area of tableview.

Comment: Here is where we experience the issue that the user scrolls quickly to a position, then we have to go to the database and get data based on the visible area and this leads to a wait time for the user since it takes few seconds to fetch the data and display from the sqlite to the visible tableview cells.

Comment: can you add timers to narrow down exactly where the bottlneck is?  My experience says that we dev's are not very good at divining where bottlenecks are.  Even if it is a timer around the call to the sqlite library.

Comment: Better yet, use this: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-shark-to-performance-tune-your-iphone-app
Or this: http://code.google.com/p/iphone-quick-profiler/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't assume that SQLite is your bottleneck.  I made that same assumption in my own application and spent days trying to optimize the database access, only to run Instruments against it and find that I had a slow string-processing routine in my interface that was bogging things down.

Use Time Profiler and Object Allocations first to verify where your hotspots are in code.  SQLite is ridiculously fast.

That said, with 4000 rows, you will probably run into memory issues at the least if you try to load all of them into an array for display to the screen.  My recommendation would be to import that data into a Core Data SQLite database and use an NSFetchedResultsController with a batch size set for its fetch request to be slightly larger than the number of rows displayed onscreen.

Core Data will handle the loading / unloading of batched data this way, meaning that only a small part of the database is loaded into memory at once.  This can lead to a tremendous speedup (particularly on the initial load) and will significantly reduce memory usage.  It also does it using a trivial amount of code.

Answer (score 0):

A properly indexed SQLite database will run circles around any flat file, especially if you have a lot of records. Also try consolidating those 10 files into 1 database, so you can perform joins on indexed columns and use clever tricks such as views. Right now it seems like you're pulling data from 10 different databases and manually comparing/processing them, which would of course take a lot of time and memory.

Comment: We are not performing joins or other operation on tables from different files. All sqlite files have same tables but the data is different. We have to display data from file 1 first, followed by file 2 and so on horizontally in a tableview. We did try having a single file. But since there are too many records it takes lot of time to download initially and the queries also run slower.

Answer (score 0):

It is going to depend on the application, how you are using and querying the data.  Profile it, confirm that sqlite is or isn't the problem.  Then attack whatever the profiling turns up.

Profilers: [Shark](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-shark-to-performance-tune-your-iphone-app)
Or [some other profiling solution](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-quick-profiler/)